# Does Uniswap allow testing swap on testnets?

Tags: testing, testnets, goerli, uniswapv2

I am testing my smart contract on goerli testnet.

Everything is working. After I complete adding an LP when I want to test whether it is able to swap, the system keep showing "Insufficient liquidity for this trade".

My question does Uniswap allow using testnet to test swaps?

Thank.

Answer (score 1):

It does support testnet mode. The error you are getting is regarding low liquidity, try swapping fewer tokens or adding more liquidity to the pool. Also, share the pool so the community members can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
Was working few days ago.
Now my liqidity pool is created:
https://www.dextools.io/app/en/ethergoerli/pair-explorer/0x93e1300f34b35b3fbcae8995bd1b73b3d3586d0d?t=1709017608883
But I cannot swap. I always receive "Insufficient liquidity for this trade".